# SonarLint res.getBody() can be null even after a null check

Tags: java, spring-boot, nullpointerexception, sonarqube, sonarlint

I can't seem to get past a SonarLint issue in my Spring Boot app. Even after a null check, I still get

```
A "NullPointerException" could be thrown; "getBody()" is nullable here.
```

Other questions have mentioned assigning it to a variable (thus the `Object resBody`) but that is also not working.

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> doSomethingCool(String foo, String bar) {
        ResponseEntity<Object> res;

        try {
            res = myService.doTheWork(foo, bar);

            if (res.hasBody() && res.getBody() != null) {
                Object resBody = res.getBody(); 
                if (res.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
                    myLogger(resBody.toString(), res.getStatusCode());
                }
             }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return customErrorHandling(res, e);
        }
        return res;
         
    }
```

How can a getBody() still be null inside of a code block that checks against null? How do I fix this in SonarLint?

Comment: Nothing in this code guarantees that `res.getBody()` always has to return the same value. The analyzer can't know that it doesn't. So if you want to please the analyzer (and/or `getBody()` could actually return a value and then null) then you'd need something like `Object resBody; if (res.hasBody() && (resBody = res.getBody()) != null) {`. Also: if you attempted a solution, then please show us **which one**, because that *should* be working.

Answer (score 2):

As [Joachim Sauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40342/joachim-sauer) mentioned, I had the declaration of the variable after the null check. So:

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> doSomethingCool(String foo, String bar) {
        ResponseEntity<Object> res;

        try {
            res = myService.doTheWork(foo, bar);

            Object resBody = res.getBody(); //<--------here

            if (resBody != null) {
                
                if (res.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
                    myLogger(resBody.toString(), res.getStatusCode());
                }
             }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return customErrorHandling(res, e);
        }
        return res;
         
    }
```